# Sync method won't work using many to many relationship Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, synchronization, laravel-5

I'm trying to attach the array of items that I have in my form to my junction table. I already given all the values stored in my tables using `foreach` loop. I loop this all in my select list.

Retrieve all records in tables:

```
$resultRecipient = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
return view ('document.create')->with('resultRecipient', $resultRecipient);
```

Form:

```
<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "recipient_id" class = "control-label">To:</label>

    <select name = "recipient_id[]" multiple class = "form-control" id = "myUserList">

            @foreach ($resultRecipient as $list)
                <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
            @endforeach

    </select>

</div>
```

Migration:

**users**

-id

-username

-password

**documents**

-id

-title

-content

-category_id - FK

**recipients_documents** (junction table)

-id

-senderUserId - FK reference to **users**

-recipientUserId - FK reference to **users**

-docu_id - FK reference to **documents**

My Models:

Document

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{    

public function recipients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Models\User');
}
}
```

User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
use Authenticatable;

public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Models\Document');
}
}
```

DocumentController:

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $document->save();
    $document->recipients()->sync($request->recipient_id, false);


    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

When I'm trying to attach the request in my form which is `recipient_id` but it error says. I just created a new folder in app named **Models**

> Class 'Models\User' not found

Can anyone tell why I get this error? Any help would appreciated!

Cheers

**UPDATE 1**

I solved this error followed steps by @jaysingkar. But when I try to `sync` this after hitting the submit button it gives me a error.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webdev.document_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `user_id` from `document_user` where `document_id` = 15)

But it insert in the document tables but in my juction table won't insert that I want to attach.

**UPDATE 2**
Thanks @jaysingkar and @mydo47 for the help and tips that you given. I already create document_user table (junction) I added a another **Foreign Key** which refenreces to **users** table.

Screenshot:

[image: Many to many]

As you can see here I linked two foreign key in the junction table. I want to insert the current user that logged-in in the `user_id` column. I have a form here which loop through my database records except the id of the current user that logged in.

Form:

```
<div class = "form-group">

<label for = "recipient_id" class = "control-label">To:</label>

<select name = "recipient_id[]" multiple class = "form-control" id = "myUserList">

        @foreach ($resultRecipient as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
        @endforeach

</select>
```

Migration for junction table:

```
public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('recipientUserId')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('recipientUserId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
 }
```

Document Controller:

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $document->save();
    $document->recipients()->sync($request->recipient_id, false);


    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

But when I try to submit it says. Is this valid that I can linked PK to two FK? I can insert the selected list in the **document_user** table but how can I insert the current user? Thanks for the help

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`document_user`, CONSTRAINT `document_user_recipientuserid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`recipientUserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `document_user` (`document_id`, `user_id`) values (27, 10))

**UPDATE 3**

I already get rid of the error so I created a `unsignedInteger` this column where the current user id will insert name `sender_id`

Migration update:

```
 Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('sender_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
```

I can get the id of the current user that logged in. But I'm thinking how can I insert the id based on the submit of the user.

DocumentController:

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    //GETTING ALL THE ID OF THE USERS IN THE DATABASE EXCEPT THE ID OF CURRENT USER.
    $resultRecipient = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();


    //GETTING ALL THE CATEGORIES.
    $resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();


    //VIEW
    return view ('document.create')->with('resultRecipient', $resultRecipient)->with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);

    if(\Auth::user()->id)
    {
        echo "You get the id";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }

}
```

Database Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Create new table document_user with document_id FK to documents and user_id FK to users. Fix function recipients(): return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'document_user', 'document_id', 'user_id');  fix function document() : return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'document_user', 'user_id', 'document_id');

Comment: Do you have the `document_user` table in your db ?

Comment: Sorry didn't see @mydo47 's comment. mydo47 could you please update your answer with the answer for 2nd problem.

Comment: @mydo47 Thanks for your tips I followed your tips but I get a error. Can you please see my updated post. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with @Marcin 's answer,
You would need to use "App\Models\User" instead of "Models\User"

```
public function recipients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

## Update for

> Base table or view not found:

You would need document_user table to be present in DB in order to work with many-to-many relationship. The table must contain the `document_id` and `user_id` columns.

Laravel's documents have explained this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: users,
>   roles, and role_user. The role_user table is derived from the
>   alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the
>   user_id and role_id columns.

Comment: same with "Models\Document". Use "App\Models\Document"

Comment: This works. But I get another error. `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webdev.document_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `user_id` from `document_user` where `document_id` = 11)`

Comment: instead of using  `$document->save();` try using `$document->create();`
I had this problem myself and this solved it 2 days back.

Comment: please use @jaysingkar in your comment so that I could get notification about the new comment.

Comment: I can't tagged you friend I don't know why. I tried the `create();` method but it gives me a error. Can you please see my post I updated my post also I can get the id of the user.

Comment: Replace your sync method with this => `$document->recipients()->sync($request->recipient_id, ['sender_id' => Auth::user()->id]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118080/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-francisunoxx).

Answer (score 1):

1. Add classmap in `composer.json` :

   `"classmap" : [
                    "database",
                    "app\Models"
    ]`
2. Change in `config\auth.php` :

   `'model' => 'App\Models\User' ,`
3. In `User` model :

   `namespace App\Models;`
4. Update composer

**Update**
Create new table `document_user` with `document_id` FK to documents and `user_id` FK to `users`.

Fix function recipients():

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'document_user', 'document_id', 'user_id');
```

Fix function document() :

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'document_user', 'user_id', 'document_id');
```

Comment: Thanks @mydo47 I tried to link PK to with two FK in my junction table but I get a error when submitting the form. It says. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`document_user`, CONSTRAINT `document_user_recipientuserid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`recipientUserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `document_user` (`document_id`, `user_id`) values (27, 10))

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons for that, I would assume you moved `User` model into `Models` directory but you haven't changed namespace.

The beginning of file should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class User
{
  // ...
```

Comment: I include the Models in my namespace but still I got this error :(